# All values are null for lag() function

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, lag

```
Select date, symbol, open, high, low, cts.close, volume, lag(cts.close) over (PARTITION by date, symbol) as prevclose, 
((cts.close - cts.open) / cts.close) * 100 as prcnt
from cts
where cts.close <> 0;
```

Keep getting null for the whole column prevclose.

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely due to fact you are partitioning by `date` column which whas time component. Every partition is unique so there is no "prev" value.

Also `LAG` without `ORDER BY` does not make sense. Order is not guaranteed.

```
SELECT ..., lag(cts.close) over (PARTITION by date, symbol) as prevclose
FROM cts;
```

In my opinion it should be sth like:

```
SELECT ..., lag(cts.close) over (PARTITION BY symbol ORDER BY date) as prevclose
FROM cts;
```